# cant use a variable set by a power automate flow in an if statement

Tags: powerapps, power-automate

HI all I have a power app that runs a flow to return some data.

```
Set(
    DocNumber,
    GetMaxNum.Run(
        "",
        Label_DocNumberPrefix.Text
    ).max_number
);
```

nothing special this will just return a number and it works fine.

However if I then try and use the below if statement I get invalid argument type expected one of the following Number, Text, Boolean, Date, Time etc...

```
If(
    IsBlank(DocNumber),
    Set(
        DocNumber,
        0
    )
);
```

Comment: Does the GetMaxNum flow 's max_number actually return an "Integer" type? It probably might not work if it is not of an "Integer" type.

Comment: @thebernardlim I am an idiot and you are awesome thank you. It was being returned as a float which for some reason it did not like.

Comment: welcome mate! Do upvote my comment too if it helped you in any way